# Autoit update image not working

Tags: user-interface, autoit

I have a code that should update a image but it does not. It works with a lable (text) but not a image. Can any one help heres my code:

```
$tmppic="Images\tmp\Nodata.bmp"
GUICreate("CPU Temp")
Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 1)
$tmpimg=GUICtrlCreatePic($tmppic,100,100,200,100)
GUISetState()
while 1
   $tmppic="Images\tmp\1.bmp"
   GUICtrlSetdata($tmpimg,$tmppic)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace GuiCtrlSetData with GuiCtrlSetImage and it should work ;)